# D3 draggable group with foreignObject HTML Input text caused it to be not edittable

Tags: html, d3.js

I have a draggable group which contain a foreignobject which in it self contains a text HTML input .

However, this causes the textbox to be not selectable/editable, since it seem the drag event swallow the mouse click event.

Can you help me with this ?

The source code is at
   http://bl.ocks.org/4334294

thank you

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered by Tore Nauta at the [d3-js google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/t3-lldZNfSA)

The trick is stop the propagation. See the last line of code below:

```
handleGroup
        .append("foreignObject")
        .attr("width", 80)
        .attr("height", 37)
        .attr('x', 10)
        .attr( 'y', 5)
        .append("xhtml:body")
        .attr('xmlns','http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
        .html("<input type='text' />")
        .on("mousedown", function() { d3.event.stopPropagation(); });
```